# Проверка наличия и запись строки в базу при отсутствии оной

Tags: mysql

Можно ли одним запросом выявить, есть ли данная строка в базе или нет, и если нет, то записать?

Answer (score 4):

А вы вообще искали хоть как-нибудь решение проблемы??? Я вот щас честно говоря не знал вообще как такое делать. Но открыл google и сразу все понятно стало:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` VALUES(x,y,z)
```

либо читайте про http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Что то у меня не работает..

Comment: А по-четче? А то мы всех экстрасенсов в отпуск отправили...

Comment: Создал тестовую таблицу, посылаю запрос:
> INSERT IGNORE INTO `tt`(`ttt`, `rrr`) VALUES (1,1)
Строка записалась, посылаю такой же запрос, сново записалась. То есть все время записывается..

Comment: Так вам нужно установить поле(я) UNIQUE, только тогда сработает. Поссылке перейдите хотяб один раз и прочтите, не ленитесь, Вам же польза от этого...